The marklines in my EChart aren't showing, why not?
Any clue why these markLines aren't showing up?
I have several charts, and the markLines are OK on the rest of them, but not this one.
I'm sure I've some goofy mistake, but I just can't find it.  I'm still relatively new to ECharts.
series: [{
    data: [
        9.192469262,
        9.214918872,
        ...
        9.2296280396,
        9.2258655988
    ],
    type: "line",
    symbol: "circle",
    lineStyle: {
        color: "#ced4da",
        width: 1.25
    },
    markLine: {
        data: [{ xAxis: 9480 }, { xAxis: 9520 }, { xAxis: 9549 }],
        silent: true,
        lineStyle: { color: "343a40", weight: 2, type: "solid" },
        label: { "show": false }
    }
}]

What I'm getting:

What I expected to get:

Thanks!

can you share full option object? because i can not find any issue with above code.

If your xAxis is of type category, the values will be transformed to strings,
so for the markLines to be shown, you have to specify the xAxis values as strings;
also, obviously, you have to have the those values on the x axis (they are just strings,
there's no interpolation possible). In the following example only two of the
three markLines are shown, since the third one doesn't have its xAxis-value among the
values of the x axis:


const myChart = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#chart'));
const options = {
    series: [{
        data: [
            9.192469262,
            9.214918872,
            9.2296280396,
            9.2258655988
        ],
        type: "line",
        symbol: "circle",
        lineStyle: {
            color: "#ced4da",
            width: 1.25
        },
        markLine: {
            data: [{ xAxis: '9480' }, { xAxis: '9520' }, { xAxis: '9549' }],
            silent: true,
            lineStyle: { color: "343a40", weight: 2, type: "solid" },
            label: { "show": false }
        }
    }],
    xAxis:{
        type: "category",
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: [9450, 9480, 9520, 9550]
    },
    yAxis:{
        type: "value",
        min: 9,
    }
};
myChart.setOption(options);
<div id="chart" style="width: 400px;height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js"></script>



Alternatively, you may have the x axis as a value axis, in which case the xAxis-values set for markLines might be numbers (strings also work, they are parsed to numbers), the way you set them, and they are interpolated, so
there's no need for the x axis to have those exact values. In this case however, the values for x data should not be places on the xAxis configuration, but in the series (minimal example):


const myChart = echarts.init(document.querySelector('#chart'));
const options = {
    series: [{
        data: [
            [9450, 9.192469262],
            [9500, 9.214918872],
            [9550, 9.2296280396],
            [9600, 9.2258655988]
        ],
        type: "line",
        symbol: "circle",
        lineStyle: {
            color: "#ced4da",
            width: 1.25
        },
        markLine: {
            data: [{ xAxis: 9480 }, { xAxis: 9520 }, { xAxis: 9549 }],
            silent: true,
            lineStyle: { color: "343a40", weight: 2, type: "solid" },
            label: { "show": false }
        }
    }],
    xAxis:{
        type: "value",
        min: 'dataMin',
        max: 'dataMax',
    },
    yAxis:{
        type: "value",
        min: 9,
    }
};
myChart.setOption(options);
<div id="chart" style="width: 400px;height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.1/echarts.min.js"></script>




thank you! I have not yet had the chance to follow up on your suggestions, but I do want to thank you for your very informative answer.  Of course I will post back here when I do get to work with this issue again.
